# Return raw JSON without any indentation or formatting from a .NET 7 Web Api endpoint request

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, .net-7.0

I have several endpoints in a .NET 7 Web Api application returning a JSON response. No matter what I do, the resulting JSON keeps being formatted with indentation, adding extra bytes to the response.

For example, this is an example of one of those responses:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Alias": "Superman",
        "FirstName": "Clark",
        "LastName": "Kent"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Alias": "Batman",
        "FirstName": "Bruce",
        "LastName": "Wayne"
    }
]
```

But this is what I need the response to be:

```
[{"Id":"1","Alias":"Superman","FirstName":"Clark","LastName":"Kent"},{"Id":"2","Alias":"Batman","FirstName":"Bruce","LastName":"Wayne"}]
```

I have already tried these options:

- Adding the JSON serializer settings to the Program.cs file, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => {
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
})
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
    });
```

- Ensuring responses are serialized and then converting them to strings using something like this: `Result.ToString(Formatting.None);`
- Converting whatever object is the result into a JObject or JArray like this:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer() {
    Formatting = Formatting.None
};

var jResult = JArray.FromObject(result, jsonSerializer);
```

None of this has made any difference whatsoever to the response.

All of the results are returned to the client using something like this:

```
return Content(result.ToString(), "application/json", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Like I said, this is happening in a .NET 7 Web Api, but I have an older version of the same Web Api application developed in .NET Framework 4.8 which does return responses without formatting, so I need to the same thing in this newer version.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I can not see any code that shows how the action returns the result. How can we help you without this? What is result? where it is defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can't show any of your action code. For example this code will certainly return not formatted string

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject,
      Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None); // You probably don't need this option also
return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

or if you use a minimal API

```
 return Results.Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

JObject.ToString() always creates a formatted json string, so if you have a JObject instance you need to use

```
jsonString = JObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```